# Providing an I-134 for a Diversity Lottery Winner

Tags: united-states, immigration

If a US citizen or a US legal Permanent Resident is providing a US diversity visa lottery winner an I-134, could that person, in the future, provide another I-134 for a different person who's trying to immigrate to the US? And are there any down sides to giving someone an I-134 like someone's PR getting revoked (other than being liable for government aid the immigrant could take)?

Comment: "other than being liable for government aid the immigrant could take" I want to point out that the I-134 is not legally binding, and does not give you any liability for anything the immigrant does.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean there's no downside to giving someone an I-134?

Answer (score 3):

**[C]ould that person, in the future, provide another I-134 for a different person who's trying to immigrate to the US?**

According to the [Instructions for Form I-134 (PDF, 371.05 KB)](https://www.uscis.gov/i-134)

> If you are sponsoring more than one foreign national, you must submit a separate Form I-134 for each foreign national.

There is no mention, that I can see, prohibiting future applications.

Comment: Look at questions 22 to 25 on the I-134--it's explicitly asking about previous I-134s and has space for two of them.  If you couldn't file multiple petitions there would be no point in the form having blanks for listing more than one.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel  Good spot, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at questions 22 to 25 on the I-134--it's explicitly asking about previous I-134s and has space for two of them. If you couldn't file multiple petitions there would be no point in the form having blanks for listing more than one.